# Return List of Columns in SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to get the list of columns off a SQL Server Compact Database and return them to a table.  This is my code:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tableName + "'";
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())                
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ColumnList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

But when I run the `reader` is throwing this exception:

> HasRows = '((System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader)reader).HasRows'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Any ideas what the problem is?  I've check with the SQL Server CE Toolbox and the database definitely has columns.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - just need to select the column_name column:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tableName + "'";
```